# access a synonym using linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using SQL server 2016

Is it possible to access a synonym from a linked server, when the actual target table of the synonym cannot be accessed by the source server?

There are two databases in one server

say on

server1

database1
database2

server2

database3

And there is a table "table1" on database1.

And a synonym for that has been created in database2

```
USE [database2]
GO

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[synonym1_for_table1] FOR [server1].[database1].[dbo].[table1]
GO
```

There is a linked server access for database2 from server2

When the following query is executed from the server2

```
SELECT * 
FROM [server1].[database2].[dbo].[synonym1_for_table1]
```

Below error is encountered

> Cannot process the object [database2].[dbo].[synonym1_for_table1]. The
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "server1" indicates that
>   either the object has no columns or the current user does not have
>   permissions on that object.

*In server2 under "linked servers", under the tree 
I see tables and views of database2 but not synonyms.
Is there a way to see synonyms. That could be a solution to this issue.*

Update:

If the synonym is made a view, the following error is observed

The server principal "xyz" is not able to access the database "database1" under the current security context.

"xyz" cannot be created/cannot be granted access to "database1".

Comment: No you cannot. This is extremely clear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) (see the big note right after "**Using Synonyms**"). But you can create a local synonym which references a remote object.

Comment: If that cannot be done, is there a workaround to access the data without exposing database1 to server2?

Comment: Create views rather than synonyms? Depends on your use case.

Comment: if view the facing following error
The server principal "xyz" is not able to access the database "database1" under the current security context.

Comment: Yeah, that message means the user you have doesn't have access to that database. From what I see you are trying to expose the data in the database without exposing the data in the database? I think your best option is to just give the user (or role) in question access to the things it needs to in database1

Answer (score -1):

1. You should create a view to read data from table present on the other server/database.
2. Also, create a separate user (service account or user account) that will have access only to read data from the source table and can execute the view(present on the different server).